# font-replacement services for Helvetica Neue

Tags: javascript, css, fonts

A project I'll be working on in the near future requires me to do some font replacement for some headings and small portions of the copy (blockquotes, etc)

The catch is that the designer wants to use Helvetica Neue.

I've looked at Typekit, Fontdeck, Google Fonts, and FontSquirrel and they don't seem to have said font nor anything really all that comparable.

I'm aware that we could use something like sIFR or Cufon, and I haven't ruled those out.

Are there any services on the web that this font can be purchased/rented/etc from?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can host fonts on your server, and use the CSS `@font-face` rule to display those fonts on your web site.  However, you need check the font license very carefully.  The fonts hosted by Google and others tend to be chosen because they have an open license.

Fonts like Helvetica have fairly strict commercial licenses.  So although you could buy one of the Helvetica variants for around $30, you might not be able to use it on the web site.  This article may be of some assistance:

http://fontfeed.com/archives/new-end-user-licence-agreement-for-fontfont/

You might also want to have a look at [Helvetica Neue: The Ugly Truth](http://angelobeltran.com/blog/articles/helvetica-neue-the-ugly-truth/), which describes how some browsers have trouble rendering your designer's font of choice.

It may be that other fonts have less restrictive licenses.  [Bitstream's Swiss 721](http://new.myfonts.com/fonts/bitstream/swiss-721/swiss-721/), for example, is very similar to Helvetica, but at first glance (and that's as far as I have got), the license is a little less restrictive.

A quick email to the font forge might be easier than reading the license.  Helvetica is a [Linotype](http://www.linotype.com/2056/contact.html) font.

Comment: fonts.com has a webfonts services in beta, and they supply all weights of Helvetica Neue. This will probably be the solution we go with. 

All that said, if there was a service / tutorial on how to host them from your own site properly, that'd be a great help. Thanks for the help!

Comment: http://typefront.com/ is a solid source for hosting your own fonts. Not quite the same as hosting from your own server (and not nearly as free) but it's an option for custom tooled fonts.

Comment: @cdutson: Hosting your own is as simple as putting the font file on your server, and specifying the URL in the `@font-face` rule. Check out this article: http://paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/ and this one: http://www.sjlwebdesign.co.uk/sjl-blog/index.php/web-design/using-font-face/ I've also just spotted this link which might be useful: http://webfonts.info/wiki/index.php?title=Commercial_foundries_which_allow_%40font-face_embedding

Comment: was going to mention http://webfonts.fonts.com with their beta program as they have so many fonts and I believe this would be a great solution whenever it launches properly (applied today for beta, waiting for my invite).

Comment: The link "The ugly truth" is no longer valid.

Comment: "The ugly truth" link is dead, but I found a similar, quite good reading, which seems to be in the same mood, claiming, that you should rather avoid using _Helvetica Neue_: "[Why Won’t Helvetica Go Away?](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/12/06/why-wont-helvetica-go-away/)".

Answer (score 9):

There's a font over at Font Squirrel called 'TeX Gyre Heros' that is very similar to Helvetica and has some versions that might fit the bill for what you are trying to do:

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/TeX-Gyre-Heros

Answer (score 2):

I've just found this and its absolutely great!! you gotta check  it.
One of the best Helvetica copies i've seen, and its free:

http://www.google.com/fonts/#QuickUsePlace:quickUse/Family:Roboto:300

Answer (score 0):

fonts.com has it:

http://webfonts.fonts.com/Project/ChooseFonts?fontQuery=helvetica#keyword%3Dhelvetica%20neue%26page%3D1

Comment: We've tried using Fonts.com and it's pretty horrible. Different styles aren't bundled into the same family, response times to load the fonts are _awful_, and the web app for administration is really bad. The only thing they have going for them is their font library, since they own pretty much every popular typeface (fonts.com is owned by Monotype, who owns Linotype, ITC, and many other subsidiaries).

Comment: Good to know! We use the self-hosted option so load times haven't been an issue. The interface is a little wonky at first but luckily you shouldn't have to spend much time in it.

Comment: Kyle, when hosting yourself, are you able to edit the CSS files so that you can properly group font styles all under the same family? It's a pretty big annoyance with fonts.com

Comment: Kevin C, can you provide more detail on what you are asking?

Comment: if you choose to have Fonts.com host the fonts, you're stuck with using font-family:'Helvetica Bold'; instead of font-family:'Helvetica'; font-weight:bold;